# Custom PHP snippet in Atom

Tags: php, atom-editor

I have been trying to add PHP snippet in Atom in MAC but the snippet does not work in the editor itself. A sample snippet I am trying to use is as below:

`'.text.html.php':
  'Paragraph tag':
    'prefix': 'ptag'
    'body': '<p>{1}</p>'`

The scope is

> text.html.php

When I try to access the snippet by typing "ptag" and hit tab nothing happens. Looks like I am missing something, help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While `.text.html.php` scope is correct you might want to extend it to HTML files. In order to do that `.text.html` and `.text.html.php` should be separated with a comma:

```
'.text.html, .text.html.php':
  'Paragraph tag':
    'prefix': 'ptag'
    'body': '<p>${1}</p>'
```

Alternatively you could set the scope to `.text.html,php`.

To position the cursor inside `p` tag you have to write `${1}` instead of `{1}`. If you want to add additional text to it you can use `${1:paragraph}`, so that it will generate `<p>paragraph</p>` and paragraph will be selected for modification.

You can read more about snippets in [Flight Manual](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)

Edit: Fixed scope as noted by Adam

Comment: Thanks! both scope notified simply works
'.text.html, .text.php' or '.text.html,php'

Comment: @Adam It works indeed. Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Where to add above?

Comment: @M.sulemanKhan To `snippets.cson` file which you can access by selecting `File > Snippets`/`Edit > Snippets`/`Atom > Snippets` menu (depending on your OS). You can find more detailed information here: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/#creating-your-own-snippets